# useEffect not firing when state is updated

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, state, use-effect

I have a useEffect hook that should be firing at the state change of currentUser. However it seems that it will fire once or twice but at refresh the currentUser value becomes null and only sometimes the useEffect does not update so I lose data my app depends on. The data from my api call that is dependent on currentUser shows initially but then is dropped.

```
const currentUser = props.currentUser || {};
const isPccIntegrated = isPCCUser(currentUser);


useEffect(() => {

some api calls...

loadEntries([]);
}, [props.currentUser]);

const loadEntries = async function(base, token){

let result = await api.UserRecords.chart(userID, token);
    if (result.pageToken) {
      // another page of entries exist, load the next page
      loadEntries(base.concat(result.items), result.pageToken);
    } else {
      // received last page of entries
      let allEntries = base.concat(result.items);

      if (isPccIntegrated) {
        try {
          // for PCC integrated patients, pull any progress note from PCC and add into the chart
          const pccNotes = await api.PCC.progressNotes(userID);
             ....
         }
       }....


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  userID: state.router.location.pathname.split("/").pop(),
  currentUser: state.common.currentUser,
});
```

This presents itself by my `loadEntries` function breaking down because it is dependent on the currentUser object. So currentUser is missing the flag for `isPCCIntegrated` is false and it stops my function.

Comment: Neither the variable `currentUser` nor `props.currentUser` are state in the code you show.

Comment: The props.currentUser Value comes from mapStateToProps. I just added it in.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mapStateToProps use the react-redux hook useSelector to access your state then put that in the useEffect dependency array in place of [props.currentUser]. When that gets updated your useEffect will fire.

`const currentUser = useSelector(state => state.common.currentUser)`

```
useEffect(() => {

some api calls...

loadEntries([]);
}, [currentUser]);
```

Comment: This solution makes sense but for some reason this fix wont compile I get an error with the new currentUser. Says `Object(...) is not a function`. Was searching for a solution and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60937090/react-redux-useselector-is-telling-uncaught-typeerror-object-is-not-a-fun) but not sure i understand the solution.

Comment: But now that Im reading more about it whats the benefit in using the useSelector hook over the mapStateToProps?

Comment: You need to remove or comment out
```some API calls...```If you are using 'spread operator' somewhere in your code then make sure your Babel config supports it.